# Запись в четные и нечетные строки в файле python

Tags: python

Есть большой файл со строками.
Как записать в начало четных строк `a:"` и в конец `"`
В начало нечетный `q:"` и в конец `",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ты хочешь чётную строку заменить на "a:содержание строки a". Читаешь весь файл в список и через for проверяешь  индекс строки. И далее собираешь новую строку или если файл слишком большой и хочется сэкономить память, то построчно пишешь в файл(но это будет медленно работать). Вот пример кода, как должно это работать.

```
with open("test.txt") as file:
    data = file.readlines()


res = ""
for l_ind in range(len(data)):
    if l_ind % 2 == 0:
        res += f"a:{data[l_ind]}a"
    else:
        pass # тут для нечётной строки

with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(res)
```